# how to access object's properties stored in list of objects c#

Tags: c#

im trying to work out if you can access an object that was added to a list (of objects) something like this:

```
public class nearshop_data
{
    public String r_name { get; set; }
    public String r_desc  { get; set; }
    public  String loc_lat  { get; set; }
    public  String loc_lon  { get; set; }
}
```

then adding to that list as you would

```
shop_data = new nearshop_data();
lo = new List<object>();

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

    shop_data.r_name = stuff.results[i].name;
    shop_data.r_desc = stuff.results[i].vicinity;
    shop_data.loc_lat = stuff.results[i].geometry.location.lat;
    shop_data.loc_lon = stuff.results[i].geometry.location.lng;

    lo.Add(shop_data);       

}
```

then i want to retrieve that in another class say in the code behind and here is where it all fails... as i cant actually access the properties of that object

any ideas on how to rewrite the code or what to use?

I'm guessing when I get the instance of that list in my code behind and lets say retrieve it at index 0 its still boxed in (or am i wrong?) - i vaguely remember something like this was done in java

Comment: Why do you have a `List<object>` when you could have a `List<nearshop_data>` ?

Comment: Also I think the variable naming could be improved

Comment: i have since changed it to List<nearshop_data>, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're using `List<object>` instead of `List<nearshop_data>` which is effectively boxing the type.

If you need to keep it like this you'd need to cast the object to the appropriate type:

`nearshop_data firstElement = (nearshop_data)lo[0];`

or even better use a `List<nearshop_data>` in the first place.

In addition because `nearshop_data` is a [reference type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/490f96s2.aspx), and you only instantiate it once, you are only adding the pointer to the same instance of `shop_data` each time.  Meaning you'll only end up with one element with the values equal to that of the last loop iteration.

Comment: And the 2nd problem is that he actually only adds one object to the list.

Comment: @Dirk - because shop_data is a reference type?

Comment: Yes, it's a class, and he only creates one instance of it.

Comment: @m.edmondson, what Dirk means is that the `new` probably needs to be inside the loop, and not on the outside, otherwise he'll end up with a list of 1 shop data instance, that'll have the values of the last one written.

Comment: Correct - I'll add this to my answer for completeness.

Comment: when i add that object to the list inside a loop would that not be enough to just instantiate it once rather than each time the object is added? since it is the same object?

Comment: @metase, your loop suggests that you need multiple *instances* of the same object for each of the results.

Comment: @m.edmondson how do i then access the properties of it (r_name, r_desc etc..) ?

Comment: @m.edmondson ah yes ms.lo.ElementAt(0) (ms being instance in code behind) finally exposed all the elements :) - wish i asked that at 4 am lol

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the item from the list back to it's specific class:

```
 nearshop_data myitem = lo[0];
```

Of course you might want to check the type of the open before you try and cast (otherwise it will throw an exception). You can either do this:

```
if (lo[0] is nearshop_data) 
{
    // do your cast here
}
```

or:

```
nearshop_data myitem = lo[0] as nearshop_data;

if (myitem != null)
{
    // myitem is a nearshop_data instance
}
```

Of course, better would be to use a more specific class in your generic list. `List<object>` is really no more useful than the old `ArrayList`. If you only need `nearshop_data` items then just use `List<nearshop_data>`. If you need a hetreogenous list then just use the most specific base class (or interface) that will cover all the items you need to store.